# Unable to find template "layout.html.twig" Symfony3

Tags: html, templates, include, twig, symfony

I have this code and it give me Error: ***Unable to find template "layout.html.twig" in Categorias\listar.html.twig at line 1.***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}LAYOUT title - CATEGORIAS{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
        {% block stylesheets %}
            <style>
                .container{
                    border: 1px solid black;
                    background: #eee;
                    width: 85%;
                    height: 300px;                    
                }
            </style>
        {% endblock %}

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            {%block container %}
                Contenido por defecto de CATEGORIAS LAYOUT
            {%endblock %}
        </div>
        {% block body %}<h1>HOLA SOY EL bloque Body por defecto de CATEGORIAS</h1>{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

```html
{% extends "layout.html.twig" %}
{%block container %}

    <h1>Contenido del body customizado en listar.html.twig</h1>
{%endblock%}
```

[Folders link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaIEl.png)

Answer (score 2):

Route must be:

```html
{% extends "Categorias/layout.html.twig" %}
{% block title %}Estas en la vista de categorias{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    
    Esto es el body de listar categorias
    
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
{% extends '::Categorias/layout.html.twig' %}
```

instead of:

```
{% extends "layout.html.twig" %}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
{% extends "app:categorias:layout.html.twig" %}

{%block container %}
    <h1>Contenido del body customizado en listar.html.twig</h1>
{%endblock%}
```

Also, if `app` is you bundle, then it should be called `AppBundle`. (It will require a lot of editing if your project is well advanced)
I would also suggest to rename `categorias` to `Categorias` (personnal taste though)

And last, but not least, if you plan to use your layout for twig files that are outside `categorias` folder, I would suggest to make a `Comun` folder in which you would place twigs that are used by other files, which would then change your code to this:

```
{% extends "app:comun:layout.html.twig" %}

{%block container %}
    <h1>Contenido del body customizado en listar.html.twig</h1>
{%endblock%}
```

And if you apply all advices, it will then become:

```
{% extends "AppBundle:Comun:layout.html.twig" %}

{%block container %}
    <h1>Contenido del body customizado en listar.html.twig</h1>
{%endblock%}
```